# Using Twilio with Rohos 2FA software for Terminal Server login

Tags: authentication, twilio, twilio-api, two-factor-authentication

Has anyone set up Rohos 2FA software using Twilio for the SMS portion?  I have updated the powershell to the proper API hook and when I test the error is not authorized, but if I go directly to the hook, I can use the same info in the script and access the XML info.  I'm not sure what I am missing.  I am new to using Twilio and Rohos.  Just trying to wrap y head around it all. PS Script is below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I need to finish getting the SMS part configured.  The system is working, but I can only use the Emergency Access portion which is answering Security Questions. Need to get the SMS up and running.
Obviously I blocked the account numbers and passwords in the script. 
Thanks for any assistance!!!

```
if ($NotifyBySms)
{
    # If phone is blank
    if ($AdUserName.mobile -eq $null)
    {
        SaveStatus -StatusText "Error $($AdUserName.sAMAccountName) - phone is empty."
        $cntNotificationsNotSent++
    } 
    # If phone is not blank - send SMS
    else
    {
        $SmsNotificationText = "OTP code is $($otp)"
        #https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx + to=$($AdUserName.mobile)+text=$($SmsNotificationText)
        #https://smsc.ru/sys/send.php?login=xxxxxxx&psw=xxxxx&phones=+$($AdUserName.mobile)&mes=$($SmsNotificationText)

        $SmsGatewayUrl = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Messages.Json&user=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&password=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&to=$($AdUserName.mobile)&text=$($SmsNotificationText)"

        $RequestResult = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $SmsGatewayUrl
        if ($RequestResult.Content -match "^OK")
        {
    SaveStatus -StatusText "SMS OK to $($AdUserName.mobile) RET: $($RequestResult.Content)."
            #do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            SaveStatus -StatusText "SMS Error: $($RequestResult.Content)."
            return -1
        }
    }
}

return $cntNotificationsNotSent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I've never used powershell before, so I'm unequipped to tell you exactly what to do.

However, I can see that there are a few things wrong with the way you are making the request to send the SMS. Here are the things you need to update:

- You need to send the request to the messages resource as a `POST` request, so add `-Method 'POST'` to your request
- You can't set the username and password (Account SID and Auth Token) as URL parameters. Instead you need to send them as HTTP basic authentication. I believe this means you need to add `-Authentication Basic` and then create a `PSCredential` object with the account sid and auth token, which you then pass as the `-Credential` option
- You need to send the parameters of the message as part of the body of the request, not in the URL, also, you don't have the right parameters, you need a `To`, a `From` and the `Body` of the message, like this:

  ```
  $Body = @{
      To = $AdUserName.mobile
      From = $YourTwilioNumber
      Body = $SmsNotificationText
  }
  ```

  Then add `-Body $Body` to your request.

I hope this helps you to construct the URL and request you need to send the SMS message.